# Antenna Design Filtering Out UnWanted Frequencies

Tags: wireless, rf, integrated-circuit

I was wondering if someone could explain to someone with no electrical engineering background where would one place the resonator whose sole responsibility is to amplify sine waves at a particular frequency while ignoring other sine waves. Would this resonator be located by the antenna itself or at a location once the signal has passed through the transmission line to the receiver for example ? I hope I have not confused the technology and further hope that I've explained the question clearly. Please correct me wherever and ask any questions for further clarification.

Answer (score 2):

The amplifier and filter can be placed in either location. It is usually more convenient to incorporate them in the receiver, but for low-level signals they are better placed close to the antenna, or incorporated within it, to improve the signal-noise ratio.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a good coax cable (low losses and good impedance matching) and good connexion to the antenna, this wouldn't degrade the signal very much and it's maybe more practical to have the amplifier by the recieving equipement, just for the practical sake of being indoors and all together. 
RF transmission is a chain, if a link is degraded that weakens all the chain. Check for same quality and performance from antenna to receiver.